# Collecting all object which created with a constructor?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any simple way of getting all objects which created with a constructor function

```
var ObjectConstructor = function(value){
    this.value = value;
    this.arr = [];

    this.someMethod= function () {
         //do something
    }
};

$.each($('.someClass'), function () {
    var o = new ObjectConstructor (this);
    o.someMethod();
})
```

I created so many objects with the help of this pattern. Now I need to collect all of them, somewhere in the process.
My solution is creating a global object outside of constructor

```
var allObjects = [];
```

and adding objects one by one to this array while generating them inside constructor function

```
allObjects.push(this)
```

Final Code :

```
var allObjects = [];

var ObjectConstructor = function(value){

    this.value = value;
    this.arr = [];

    this.someMethod= function () {
         //do something
    }

    allObjects.push(this)

};

$.each($('.someClass'), function () {
    var o = new ObjectConstructor (this);
    o.someMethod();
})
```

Now I can use allObjects array.

My question: Is my solution OK? Or is there any better approach for this. Thank you.

Comment: In future, you can just copy/paste your code into [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and see if it works

Comment: thank you but I know it works. I just want to learn a better approach if there is. Something like using Prototype, instanceOf... etc methods.

Comment: Shouldn't *allObjects* be a property of *ObjectConstructor*? There could also be a method to remove a member from the array.

Comment: yes absolutely right.

Answer (score 3):

> My solution is creating a global object outside of constructor `var allObjects = [];`

Yes, that's basically how to do this. However, you need to notice that this could be a memory leak, when you forget to remove objects from the array that are no more needed.

> Is there any better approach for this.

That depends on [what you think to need this for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).